# ElixirLS Code Completion Not Working in Visual Studio Code Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, code-completion, elixirls

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the ElixirLS extension in Visual Studio Code where the code completion feature is not working as expected. I've followed the recommended installation steps, but despite that, I'm not seeing any code completion suggestions while writing Elixir code.

I have:

- Erlang/OTP 26 and Elixir 1.15.4.
- installed the ElixirLS extension version 1.16.0.

I've confirmed that the extension is enabled and there are no apparent errors in the extension's output.

Is anyone else facing a similar issue or has anyone encountered this before? Could someone please guide me through the troubleshooting steps to resolve this code completion problem? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to get the code completion feature working again.

Comment: There is two issues in the `elixir-ls` repo that describe this bugs: [Not starting on OTP26](https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls/issues/886), for the Windows version [0.15.1 crash or hang on start](https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls/issues/927) and another bug in the `vscode-elixir-ls` repo [Not starting on OTP 26 on Windows](https://github.com/elixir-lsp/vscode-elixir-ls/issues/365) Giving a quick read, probably we need to wait to a new version of `elixir-ls` with the fix.